# Update listview item color with some animation flutter

Tags: flutter

#### My project

Hi,
I am trying to build a multi selection menu for my flutter application. Final result Should be something like this mockup.

[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsS1t.png)
[Selected Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQfiQ.png)

In order to achieve this i've built two widgets: one that handle the list and the other for rendering list objects.

#### Code

```
class ButtonPicker extends StatefulWidget {    
  @override
  _ButtonPickerState createState() => _ButtonPickerState();
}

class _ButtonPickerState extends State<ButtonPicker> {
  int _selectedItem = -1;
  List<String> _data = [
    'item',
    'item',
    'item',
    'item'
  ];

  void callback(int selectedIndex) {
    print(selectedIndex);
    setState(() {
      _selectedItem = selectedIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: _data.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
          return ButtonSwitch(
            text: _data[i],
            callback: callback,
            index: i,
            color: _selectedItem == i ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Here is the Item Widget

```
 class ButtonSwitch extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function(int) callback;
  final String text;
  final int index;
  final Color color;
  ButtonSwitch({
    @required this.callback,
    @required this.index,
    this.text,
    this.color,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
      child: FlatButton(
          color: color == null ? Colors.white : color,
          textColor: Colors.black,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 0, 15),
            child: Text(
              text == null ? 'Button' : text,
              style: DialogButtonStyle,
            ),
          ),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            callback(index);
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Problem

So far i can easily get the selected item and repaint the selected item but, in order to achieve this i needed to rebuild the entire list. Is there a way to change a single child item color with some simple fade-out color animation? without rebuilding the all list?

Hope my english is good enough to explain the problem

Comment: you can try to wrap your listView it with Streambuilder and using the method of bloc, so you don't need to rebuild all the list item, and you can rebuild only the designated item you want

Comment: thanks, i will definitely try